# How to plot a list with multiple data frames in one graph using ggplot in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, ggplot2, plot

In the following list, there are several data frames representing time series of some variable:

```
list.data <- list(data.frame(x=c(1:10), y=rnorm(10)),data.frame(x=c(11:20), y=rnorm(10)))
```

How can I plot these time series in one graph using `ggplot` by looping without the need of making the entry manually.
when I tried using `lapply` each time series has been plotted in a different graph.

```
lapply(list.data, function(z){ggplot()+geom_line(data=z, aes(x, y))})
```

manually plot is tedious as I have so many items on the list

```
ggplot()+geom_line(data=list.data[[1]], aes(x, y))+
         geom_line(data=list.data[[2]], aes(x, y), col='red')
```

Is there any easy way to plot without repeating `geom_line` several times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a list to `ggplot()`

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() + 
  lapply(list.data, function(z) geom_line(data = z, aes(x, y)))
```

[image]

---

Given OP's example data, we could first `rbind` the data, and then plot

```
ggplot(data = do.call(rbind, list.data)) + 
  geom_line(aes(x, y))
```

**Data**

```
set.seed(42)
list.data <- list(data.frame(x=c(1:10), y=rnorm(10)),data.frame(x=c(11:20), y=rnorm(10)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Transform the data using pivot_longer or fortify from zoo package.